# Check for empty attribute jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I'm trying to check an element for an empty attribute, but can't seem to get things to work.

Here's my html code:

```
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itemBtn" style="visibility:hidden;">
        </div>
        <div class="itemText" itemtype="loader">
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itemBtn">
        </div>
        <div class="itemText" itemtype="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's a jquery hover function that essentially just turns on the button. I was trying to build upon it by saying 'if theres no itemtype, dont turn it on'

```
    inner.find(".item").hover(function () {
        if (inner.find(".item-text[itemtype='']")) {
            $(this).children(".itemBtn").css("visibility", "hidden");
        } else {
            $(this).children(".itemBtn").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
     }, function () {
        $(this).children(".itemBtn").css("visibility", "hidden");
     });
```

UPDATE:
I ended up solving this by doing the following:

```
    inner.find(".item").hover(function () {
         if ($(this).find("div[itemtype='']").length) {
           $(this).children(".itemBtn").css("visibility", "hidden");
         } else {
           $(this).children(".itemBtn").css("visibility", "visible");
         }
         }, function () {
           $(this).children(".itemBtn").css("visibility", "hidden");
         });
```

Comment: And? What happens when you run the code?

Comment: You should use .attr() and conditionally check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's just simple example

```
var attr = $(this).attr('title');
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
    //do some thing
}
```

Comment: My only issue with that is (this) is the parent, I need to check the child. Using your example, I'd think to do: 
        var attr = $(this).children().attr('title');
But it doesn't work

Comment: or just use $("#child_id") if U can use id with the child

Comment: another solution `var attr = $(this).find("child_selector").attr('title');`

Comment: what i want to say that with jquery U can do something with more than 1 way just search

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr` like this with a conditional:

```
var attr = $(this).attr('title');
if (!attr) {
    // Do something
}
```

Or you can make it more concise by checking the attribute in the conditional like this:

```
if (!$(this).attr('title')) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (! $('.item-text').attr('itemtype') ) {
    alert("Nothing in itemtype");
} else {
    alert("Not empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, just check to see if the attribute exists or not using [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), like so:

```
if (!$(this).attr('title')) {
    alert('Exists!');
}
```

Comment: It seems when I do this method its saying that itemtype="" still returns positive, whereas I want it to have a different effect. When I implemented this I go the hover effect on both elements